# How to mock an excel file to test a specific method

Tags: ruby, excel, rspec

I would like to test with Rspec that a method (#validate) reads an excel file and returns an array of hashes. I don't know how to mock an excel file. I know I expect the result to be [{name: "name"}, {birthday: "birthday"}, {email: "email"}] But I don't know very good how to create a mock of excel file.

By the moment I have this:

```
require 'spec_helper'
require './models/vip_client.rb'

describe VipClient do
  describe "#validate" do
    it "creates an array of hashes from an excel file" do
      # arrange code....     
      expect(VipClient.validate(excel_file)).to eq([{name: "David"}, {birthday: "13/12/1985"}, {email: "davidemail@gmail.com"}])
    end
  end
end
```

My problem is that I don't know how to build the excel_file content to manipulate it later inside the validate method

Comment: If this is even possible (a real Excel file is quite complex) or how it might be done depends on the implementation of `VipClient.validate`. Did you wrote that method? Is that method part of a gem?

Comment: that method is part of the class VipClient. But I haven't still implemented the method as I expect to do it from doing tests...but I don't know how to arrange the spec...I need to fake that I have an excel file to call later the VipClient.validate(excel_file), but I don't know how to fake that excel

Comment: Just create small real excel file and use it in your test.

Comment: Thank you¡¡ It's what I've done finally and I think is the solution I needed. I was trying to avoid it but is a good solution